# May I, or may I not ask part specific questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm  new to the world of microcontrollers. I would like to know whether the part I selected is pertinent to my specific case, or if I have misinterpreted something.

The question guidelines specifically mention that I should ask a general question, rather than a case specific one. If not, I'm  just feeling around in the dark and the forum is of no use.

Comment: Note that this is not a forum, so guidelines you know from classical forums often do not apply. You can always formulate questions in a way that they are somewhat general but fit to your specific part too. Instead of "Is the 78M05 input transient response fast enough for me?" you can ask "My requirements are X, will an input transient response of Y match this?" and you got a question that will be more helpful for future users and likely lead to an explanation of why it does or does not match it, which others can use to judge this case on their own.

Comment: "The question guidelines specifically mention that I should ask a general question, rather than a case specific one." ... Perhaps I need to study the guidelines a bit more myself. Could you please reference where this is mentioned? From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): The first item says "a specific electronics design problem".

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible, but you have to be careful as you're walking a tight line.  If not done right, this can easily be a shopping question.  That will get your question summarily closed.

Trying to flip it around, as you are suggesting, probably also won't work in the naive case.  *"Will this PIC 16F84 be able to do bass and treble controls on my HiFi audio stream?"* will also be closed as being stupid, with a RTFM or two in the comments for good measure.

A better way to ask this might be *"What parameters do I need the A/D and D/A in a microcontroller to have to perform bass and treble control on my HiFi audio stream?"*.  That might fly, but mentioning a micro complicates the real question, which is really about A/D and D/A specs (or is it about what HiFi audio really is?).

Think carefully about what the real question is.  Which micro to use is too high a level.  Drill down and find out what you really need help with, which is most likely specs of a peripheral relative to your application.  Ask about that, but give us some context too.  Going too deep is another common problem here.  As I said, you're walking a tight line with this kind of question, which is why some of what I'm saying probably sounds contradictory.

Reasonable questions related to the above example might be *"What are the relevant characteristics of HiFi audio for picking the A/D and D/A of a digital bass and treble control?"*, or *"Is this AD98765-A [link to datasheet] with 16 bit resolution at 48 kHz good enough for digitizing a HiFi audio stream that I want to do bass/treble control on?  It has ±5 LSB non-linearity.  Should I get the B version with only 2 LSB non-linearity?  This is a one-off for personal use in my living room."*.  Note the important context provided by the last sentence.  *"This is for a custom setup in my professional recording studio."* might yield different answers.

Comment: I tried to follow your unofficial guidelines as best I could...my question can be found <a href="http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169295/will-the-pic18f14k50-perform-well-as-a-cnc-machine-micro-processor">here</a>. If I made a mistake, I would love to know as to get a better answer, ask a better question, and help the health of the site.